# Triggering "Reset Password" option in macOS Ventura for a specific account from the command line

Tags: shell-script, security, password, macos

I ran this command first to open the "Users and Groups" preferences on macOS Ventura:

```bash
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Accounts.prefPane
```

Next, I want to run a command that triggers the "Reset Password" option for a specific account so that the current user does not have to select it.

I tried various ways with the `sysadminctl` command, but it does not work. Does anyone have any more suggestions I can try?

Comment: Check for sysadminctl command with the -resetPasswordForUser | https://macnotes.wordpress.com/2019/03/28/user-management-create-remove-change-password-secure-token-from-macos-command-line/

Comment: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would probably get you Mac-specific answers

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Do you want to set a new password on an account on macOS (you can do this with `passwd`), or do you want to force a user to change their password?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! If you need help merging U&L accounts, please use the [Contact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of any page.

Comment: I am trying launch the the "reset password" within a specific/standard account under the "Users & Groups" **System Settings**. This command takes you there:
**open** /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Accounts.prefPane Now, with the picture I attached, how do I launch that from terminal?[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DydyL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DydyL.png)

Comment: Was a matter of minutes on ChatGPT, after 6 useless or wrong answers

Answer (score 0):

`pwpolicy` is a command-line utility specifically used to manage password policies on macOS. It allows you to set and modify password policies, such as password expiry, password complexity requirements, account lockouts, and more. `pwpolicy` operates on a separate password policies database.

To invite the user Max la menace to change his password the next time he logs in, you may enter this command:

```
pwpolicy -u maxlamenace -setpolicy newPasswordRequired=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct sysadminctl command is

```
sysadminctl -adminUser <adminuser> -adminPassword <adminpassword> -resetPasswordFor <user> -newPassword <newpassword>
```

Replace placeholders in above command

```
<adminuser> - Should also posses the secure token
<adminpassword> - <adminuser>'s password
<user> - for which you want to reset password
<newpassword> - password you want to set for <user>
```